# DocuSign error when Integrated with Conga button's parameter DS7=17?

Tags: docusign, conga, congo-composer

I am trying to integrate Conga with DocuSign in Salesforce. While doing that, I have entered certain parameters into Conga button like

```
&DocuSignVisible=1
&DocuSignR1ID={!Opportunity.OwnerId}
&DocuSignR1Role=Signer+1
&DocuSignR1Type=Signer
&DocuSignR1RoutingOrder=1
&DS7=17
```

From what I can see, I believe I have included all the parameters for the Conga button for DocuSign. However, when i was trying to produce the DocuSign email and send it to the Signer, it gave me the below error:

```
Error: CreateEnvelope in DocuSignAPI. The UserID did not identify a User in the system.
```

However if anyone knows what could have cause the DocuSign problems, please let me know. It doesn't have the same error when I disable DIS=17 (automate docusign delivery) and do it manually. Or is it something that I might have missed out on the DocuSign or Conga configuration which have caused the error?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Figured out the what the problem was, it was because the DocuSign user hasn't been added in DocuSign back-end. The user features do not exist when I used the trial version, but became visible when I used the sandbox version as I can see more function/features on the layout like permissions for users.

Comment: Hi @ShineAndLearn, I am having the same issue but couldn't figure out where can I find DocuSign back-end to add user. Can you please help? Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Turns out I had the same problem and the issue was with my salesforce user email address (not login) was different to the Docusign user email address. I added in a user that corresponded with that and it worked first go